# How to save the text from a dynamically created textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, passwords

Howdy  I have a form that holds labels and textboxes that will be containing passwords to folders created by the program.Everytime they click on the save new passwordbutton it creates a new textbox and label on the form. I want to save the passwords so that if they make a change to the folder it will ask if they wish to keep the changes and then they have to enter the password for that folder.My question is how to save that password to that folder.they can add or delete the password from the settings if they wish.Here is the code I am using to create the new textboxes.The text in the boxes and labels are only for testing.The form that is called list is where the textboxes will showand that is only showing here for testing purposes

```
public partial class Passworddata : Form
{
    public List<TextBox> TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
    public List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
    public Passworddata()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        Label labl = new Label();

        int i = TextBoxes.Count + 1;
        tb.Location = new Point(30,i *30);
        labl.Location = new Point(1,i*30);
        tb.Width = 30;
        tb.Name = "ID" + i;
        labl.Text = "hi";
        tb.Text = "hello";
        TextBoxes.Add(tb);
        labels.Add(labl);
        Forms.list.Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
        Forms.list.Panel1.Controls.Add(labl);
        Forms.list.Show();

    }




}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, and show the code that generates the textboxes. Question in it's current stage is too broad and unclear

Comment: Ok I added the code

Comment: Could someone tell me what the downvotes are for??I don't think that downvoting questions from new guys in c# helps them out

Comment: The text of your question is unformatted, you attempt to explain irrelivant parts of your program making the question hard to read, and there are possibly millions of ways of saving data into a file. The fact that your textboxes are dynamically generated have no impact on the question of saving text to a file. Unless you don't know how to get a hold of a reference to said textbox, but that would be a different question all together. All-in-all, lots of improvements CAN be made, could you tell me why you think your question is good and clear? I'll upvote if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specifically save the controls and data, I would suggest the following:

### For saving:

1. When the user adds a value, build a string like so:

   ```
   string currentEntry = tb.Name + "|" + tb.Text.Replace("|","~") + "|" + labl.Text;
   ```
2. Then simply use the `File.AppendAllText` method, like so:

   ```
   File.AppendAllText("SavedData.dat", currentEntry);
   ```

### For loading:

1. Subscribe to the `Form.Load` event for the `Forms.list` Form
2. Read the saved data file if it exists
3. Parse each line for the values needed
4. Create and add the controls in the `Form.Load`

### So, to be clear, inside the Method that handles the `Form.Load` event for `Forms.list` you would have something like the following code:

```
    if(File.Exists("SavedData.dat"))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("SavedData.dat"))
        {
            string line = "";
            while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)  
            {
                string[] lineData = line.Split('|');
                if(lineData.Length == 3)
                {
                    string currentTbName = lineData[0];
                    string currentTbText = lineData[1];
                    string currentLablText = lineData[2];

                    //LOAD THEM AS NORMAL
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be better served creating a usercontrol that encapsultes your label and password. Then instead of having to rely on two lists of items you only have one.

Create a UserControl and put a Label and a Textbox on it.

You should also add a Changed property:

```
public bool PasswordChanged { get; set; } = false;
```

Create a public property for the password:

```
public string Password
{
    get
    {
        return(textbox1.Text);
    }
    set
    {
        textbox1.Text = value;
        Changed = false;
    }
}
```

and one for the directory label:

```
public string Directory
{
    get
    {
        return(label1.Text);
    }
    set
    {
        label1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

On the textbox, subscribe to the TextChanged event from the designer then in the handler code put:

```
Changed = true;
```

On your main form put a FlowLayoutPanel and an Add button.

Then when you click the Add button you can add a new instance of your Password usercontrol:

```
public void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Password pwd = new Password();
    flowlayoutpanel1.Controls.Add(pwd);
}
```

On your form load event you can read in the file and create the Password controls:

Assuming you're storing your directory/passwords in a class caled PasswordEntry:

```
public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<PasswordEntry> entries = LoadEntries(@"C:\YourFile");
    foreach(PasswordEntry entry in entries)
    {
        Password pwd = new Password() { Directory = entry.Directory, Password = entry.Password };
        flowlayoutpanel1.Controls.Add(pwd);
    }
}
```

Then to identify and save your changes you can either completely overwrite your file or only update the changed entries.

To get only the changed entries you can use some linq:

```
foreach(Password pwd in flowlayoutpanel1.Controls.OfType<Password>().Where(p => p.Changed).ToList())
{
    SaveChange(pwd.Directory, pwd.Password);
}
```

Assuming you have a method called SaveChange that takes the directory string and password string and knows how to write back to your file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped me to think thru what i was doing more clearly